# Why I can't start the NameNode in this Hadoop 1.2.1 installation?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am new in Apache Hadoop and I am following a video course on Udemy.

The course is based on **Hadoop 1.2.1**, is it a too old version? Is better start my study with another course based on a more recent version or is it ok?

So I have installed **Hadoop 1.2.1** on an **Ubuntu 12.04** system and I have configured it in **pseudo distribution mode**.

According with the tutorial I have do it using the following settings in the following configuration files:

1. **conf/core-site.xml**:

   fs.default.name
            hdfs://localhost:9000
2. **conf/hdfs-site.xml**:

   dfs.replication
            1
3. **conf/mapred-site.xml**:

   mapred.job.tracker
            localhost:9001

Then in the Linux shell I do:

```
ssh localhost
```

So I am connected through SSH to my local system.

Then I go into the Hadoop bin directory, **/home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/** and here I perform this command that have to perform the format of the name node (what exactly means?):

```
bin/hadoop namenode –format
```

And this I the obtained output:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ ./hadoop namenode –format
16/01/17 12:55:25 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = andrea-virtual-machine/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [–format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_79
************************************************************/
Usage: java NameNode [-format [-force ] [-nonInteractive]] | [-upgrade] | [-rollback] | [-finalize] | [-importCheckpoint] | [-recover [ -force ] ]
16/01/17 12:55:25 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at andrea-virtual-machine/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$
```

Then I try to start all the nodes performing this command:

```
./start–all.sh
```

and now I obtain:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ ./start-all.sh 
starting namenode, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-namenode-andrea-virtual-machine.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-datanode-andrea-virtual-machine.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-secondarynamenode-andrea-virtual-machine.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-jobtracker-andrea-virtual-machine.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-tasktracker-andrea-virtual-machine.out
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$
```

Now I try to open in the browser the following URLs:

```
http//localhost:50070/
```

and can't open it (page not found)

and:

```
http://localhost:50030/
```

this is correctly opened and redirect to this jsp page:

```
http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp
```

So, in the shell I perform the **jps** command that lists all the running Java process for the user:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ jps
6247 Jps
5720 DataNode
5872 SecondaryNameNode
6116 TaskTracker
5965 JobTracker
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$
```

As you can see seems that the **NameNode** is not started.

On the tutorial that I am following say that:

> If NameNode or DataNode is not listed than it might happen that the
> namenode's or datanode's root directory which is set by the property
> 'dfs.name.dir' is getting messed up. It by default points to the /tmp
> directory which operating system changes from time to time. Thus, HDFS
> when comes up after some changes by OS, gets confused and namenode
> doesn't start.

So to solve this problem provide this solution (that can't work for me).

First stop all nodes by the **stop-all.sh** script.

Then I have to **explicitly set the 'dfs.name.dir' and 'dfs.data.dir'**.

So I have created a **dfs** directory into the Hadoop path and into this directory I have created 2 directories (at the same level): **data** and **name** (the idea is to make two folders inside it which would be used for datanode demon and namenode demon).

So I have something like this:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs$ tree
.
├── data
└── name
```

Then I use this configuration for the **hdfs-site.xml** where I explicitly set the previous 2 directories:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs/data/</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs/name/</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

So, after this changing, I run again the command to **format the NameNode**:

```
hadoop namenode –format
```

And I obtain this output:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs$ hadoop namenode –format16/01/17 13:14:53 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = andrea-virtual-machine/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [–format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_79
************************************************************/
Usage: java NameNode [-format [-force ] [-nonInteractive]] | [-upgrade] | [-rollback] | [-finalize] | [-importCheckpoint] | [-recover [ -force ] ]
16/01/17 13:14:53 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at andrea-virtual-machine/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs$
```

So I start again all the nodes by: **start-all.sh** and this is the obtained output:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-namenode-andrea-virtual-machine.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-datanode-andrea-virtual-machine.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-secondarynamenode-andrea-virtual-machine.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-jobtracker-andrea-virtual-machine.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-andrea-tasktracker-andrea-virtual-machine.out
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$
```

Then I perform the **jps** command to see if all the nodes are correctly started but this is what I obtain:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ jps
8041 SecondaryNameNode
8310 TaskTracker
8406 Jps
8139 JobTracker
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$
```

The situation worsened because now I have 2 nodes that are not started: the **NameNode** and the **DataNode**.

What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue and start all my nodes?

Comment: hadoop version command is working????

Comment: add java home in hadoop.env file

Comment: can you paste the hosts file here-- vi /etc/hosts

Comment: Can you post namenode logs

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to turn.of the IPTABLES.once and reformat along with exporting the java path.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have configure in hdfs-site.xml with ,
While you are formatting name node

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs/name/</value>
 </property>
```

then while formatting name node you should see

```
> successfully formatted /home/andrea/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs/name/
```

message if name node format is successful. As per your logs I am not able to see those successful logs. Check permission issues may be there.
If it didn't start try using another command:

```
hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
```

Hope it works...